# Derivation of four-velocity using proper time?

Tags: special-relativity

Let us say we have an accelerating particle. 4-velocity is given by the derivative of 4-position with respect to proper time. Derivations that I have seen say that:
$$d\tau=\frac{dt}{\gamma}$$
But why is this not
$$d\tau=\frac{dt}{\gamma}+td(\frac{1}{\gamma})$$ 
Since $$\tau=\frac{t}{\gamma}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because:

$$ \tau \ne \frac{t}{\gamma} $$

It's true that:

$$ \frac{d\tau}{dt} = \frac{1}{\gamma} $$

But in general this does not simply integrate to $\tau = t/\gamma$. This is true only in the special case of non-accelerated motion.